# Exporting contacts from database to outlook using php

Tags: php, csv, outlook, export

Hi guys I'm building a facility to be able to generate a csv file for import into outlook. However the thing is that my web application allows the user to enter unlimited contact entires i.e a contact can have unlimited telephone addresses, emails and other user defined fields which apprently aren't in outlook - yet I need a way to be able to export atleast all these fields into outlook using php.

How can I handle this considering that outlook stores a limited number of telephones and emails for each contact and how woudl I be able to enter user defined fields into outlook using a user defined csv. I'm using php here - my database structure is kinda liek this:

```
CONTACTS:
ID | NAME | .....

CONTACT_INFO
ID | TYPE | DETAILS | CONTACT_ID

// where type can be phone, fax, email and details are the actual number or email address etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can override the outlook limits, 
you have 2 choices that i see:

1. limit you php application (why should they need unlimited phones and addresses?)
2. split a large  contact to several enteries with the same name

Comment: How about the notes field in outlook - could that be used to accommodate the extra details? Or is there a limit on how much information can be put into a csv field or imported into an outlook field

Comment: In some cases there is a 999 character limit but if you use outlook 2003 and  
  
a new Unicode pst, there shouldn't be a limit.